# Проблемы с установкой Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Установил Node, NPM. При попытке установить Vue - всё идёт хорошо. Но когда я хочу либо посмотреть версию Vue, либо начать с ней работать через VSC - комп не видит её. Менял пути в Path, кидая туда пути к node через Users и т.д. Очень сильно не хочу переустанавливать винду из-за проблем с Vue, но очень хочу с ней работать. Подскажите, может я тупой и банально устанавливаю не туда?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас пути к `npm` должны быть прокинуты в `path` для вызова команд, если Вы хотите пользоваться Vue-Cli через внутренние команды.

В path добавить, если отсутствует (заменить [ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ] на Ваш в системе):

```
C:\Users\[ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

VSCode после добавления и сохранения просто перезапустить. Если всё сделано правильно и Вы всё действительно установили (включая Vue-Cli, он должен быть установлен глобально), то всё будет работать.

---

Но не понимаю Вашей паники, всё, что нужно от Vue, так это инициализировать проект, это можно сделать и без Vue-Cli, а просто через npm.